# How to match values on one column to another using SQL? I'm matching ID's. I need both columns to allign with the same ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example of what the output needs to look like.

```
GameID  Name       LegacyGUID      AssociatedGUID
 807    Hujim       567890-ABDE    567890-ABDE
```

Comment: What does "need both columns to align" mean?

Comment: Both the LegacyGUID and AssociatedGUID need to have matching ID's and be on the same row. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by `where` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME as t
WHERE  t.column_1 = t.column_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `self join` same table. This way you can pick and choose columns from each table:

```
select t.GameName,  t.LegacyGUID,   t.CreatedOn,    t.ModifiedOn,t1.AssociatedGUID
from table_name as T
join table_name as T1 on t.AssociatedGUID = t1.LegacyGUID
```

Based on your example in comments below here is the complete script:

```
create table #temp
(
GameName varchar(255),
LegacyGUID varchar(255) ,
CreatedOn varchar(255),
ModifiedOn varchar(255),
AssociatedGUID varchar(255) 
)

insert into #temp
values('Pacman','8F1EC35F-5105-DF11-AC31','21:31.0','19:45.0', '375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7') 
,('Sonic','375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7','46:15.0','03:48.0','A64DC346-834E-E011-A2E0 ')


select t1.GameName, t1.LegacyGUID,  t1.CreatedOn,   t1.ModifiedOn,t2.AssociatedGUID
from #temp t1
join #temp t2 on t1.LegacyGUID = t2.AssociatedGUID

drop table #temp
```

Results:

```
GameName    LegacyGUID  CreatedOn   ModifiedOn  AssociatedGUID
Sonic   375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7 46:15.0 03:48.0 375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7
```

Comment: I tried that but the rows don't match up with each other. The LegacyGUID has one ID while the AssociatedGUID has another.

Comment: please add sample data from your table  to your post for us.

Comment: Below is an example of what it currently looks like when i use the above query.GameID GameName LegacyGUID AssociatedGUID
        807           HUJIM       567890-ABDE    234590-ACFG
       809           WING       789021-AYUT    890761-POYH

Comment: example you provided doesn't have common values between LegacyGUID  and AssociatedGUID.. What is your criteria for matching records?

Comment: The matching values are the GUID ID's in both columns. The above is an example of the output I got when i ran your script. I would like both of the columns to match each other with the same GUID ID's.

Comment: GameID GameName LegacyGUID AssociatedGUID
 810          BIM               567890-ABDE 567890-ABDE
817          FLIP        789021-KIGH 789021-KIGH

Comment: Fron the example you provided above,It doesn't make any sense. In  your actual table if you have LegacyGUID and AssociatedGUID on same row already. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The issue is both LegacyGUID and AssociatedGUID are not on the same row and I'm trying to get them to be.

Comment: So show us the data where both ids are not on same row

Comment: GameName LegacyGUID CreatedOn ModifiedOn AssociatedGUID
Pacman 8F1EC35F-5105-DF11-AC31 21:31.0 19:45.0 375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7
Sonic 375BFE1A-84D8-DF11-82A7 46:15.0 03:48.0 A64DC346-834E-E011-A2E0
The Game Sonic should have both LegacyGUID and AssociatedGUID on the same row but it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you Kashif! This really helps.